# Entity Developer/EntityFramework - The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Devart Entity Developer with Entity Framework 6. I have my main class library project. I had a different Winform project altogether that uses Entity Developer/Entity Framework that I developed to do some database work with Sql. I decided to add this secondary Winform project to the main class library.

First I tried adding the Winform project to the solution. That did not work well. Even though I added a reference to the exe of the Winform project it seems not to find it ok. I removed that project from the solution.

As a second attempt. I copied the classes from the Winform project (two of them) to the main class library project and recreated the Entity Developer/Entity Framework stuff. Now when I run the project everything runs (including the new form) but I cannot connect to the database. I get the error:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

The line that has the error is the line calling base:

```
    public SWPDMEngVaultEntities() :
            base(@"name=SWPDMEngVaultEntitiesConnectionString", "SWPDMEngVaultEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

My connection string is in the app.config file and looks like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SWPDMEngVaultEntitiesConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel1.csdl|res://*/DataModel1.ssdl|res://*/DataModel1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=XXXXXX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

All of the XXXXXX's in the above string have been confirmed as correct. Also, Entity Developer has a "Test Connection" and the test connection connects just fine. Entity Developer also gets the database information OK so I know it is able to connect without issue. The problem is at runtime on the solution.

I have looked at other posts about this error and they all seem to be saying make sure your connection string is good. What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue came from Devart. Class libraries do not use app.config files for settings. By default the connection string in the Devary generated templates are stored in the app.config file. There is a place to turn this off when the model is generated.